# How to fix: TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["Location"]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using Next.js, and I have a login page. When I use specific character such as `š` on username and write wrong password, I am facing with this error. When I use normal characters on username and write wrong password, I am not facing with this error.

I checked some links about this issue like:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17907
https://github.com/fastify/fastify/issues/3217

But they were not helpful for me.

Here is the function I use to Login:

```
signIn('credentials', {
        callbackUrl:
          window.origin + (signInCallbackUrl ? signInCallbackUrl : '/'),
        username: $username.current?.value,
        password: $password.current?.value,
      });
    }
```

Is there any other thing that I can try?

Comment: one of those github post suggested EncoudeURI did u try that?

Comment: Yes. After I used encodeURIComponent on the right place, it worked. Thank you.

Comment: i suggest you post as a comment what worked. That way it helps others.